# Click and Hold then redirecting the page

Tags: html, css, jss

Help me identify what's wrong, I want the page to be redirected after a certain amount of time, let's say 2 sec, clicking and holding the button, but if the amount of time hasn't exceeded 2 sec, the timer reset. And the page only redirected only after the button released.

in html:

```
<div class="text-holder" id="button" style="display:none">
  <div class="body-border load"></div>
  <h2 class="text-holder-click show click-hold-anim">click and hold</h2>
  <h2 class="text-holder-hold hide hold-anim" id="text-hold">hold</h2>
</div>
```

While the javascript was:

```
 var timeout_id = 0,
     hold_menu = $('#button'),
     hold_time;

 hold_menu.mousedown(function () {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(hold_time);
    if (hold_time < 2000) {
    clearTimeout;
    } event.preventDefault();
 }).on('mouseup click', function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
    timeout_id = setTimeout(window_location, hold_time);
 });

 function window_location() {
 window.location.href = 'certain_page.html'
 };
```

Comment: what are you not using simple `setTimeout` function along with the `clearTimeout` function

Comment: do you mean set the setTimeout for a certain amount of time, then on the event mouseup, trigger the clearTimeout function?

Comment: yes tht is the esaiest way to do it

Comment: i'll try it again, maybe i have made a mistake. Last time i tried, the setTimeout and clearTimeout function will trigger the event but not instantly. Like there's some time after mouseup event, before the page get redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, you can easily use setTimeout and clearTimeout as such:

Here, I have tried to keep the html as similar to yours. For testing purposes, I got rid of the second h2, and kept just the first one. I have removed the style="display:none" so I can see the h2 element that needs to be clicked and held, and I've added the id of "click-hold" to that h2 elements so our jQuery listeners can fire

```js
let timeout_id;
let time_passed = 0;

 $("#click-hold").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //set interval when mouse is held down; it will increase time_passed by 1 every 1000ms(1s) and
    //append it to a div to show curr time passed
    timeout_id = setInterval(()=>{time_passed+=1; $("#append_here").empty().append(time_passed);}, 1000);
 });

 $("#click-hold").on('mouseup', function (e) {
   //button was released; clear interval that's been adding to time_passed
   clearInterval(timeout_id);
   
   //check if the time passed was greater or equal to 2(equivalent to 2s). This can be changed to 3,
   //4, 5, etc with each representing time elapsed in seconds. If condition is met, redirect. If not,
   //reset time_passed to 0
   if(time_passed >= 2){
      window.location.href="https://stackoverflow.com";
   }else{
      time_passed = 0;
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body style="text-align:center">
        <p>PAGE WILL REDIRECT AFTER 2s HOLDING TEXT BELOW</p>
        <div class="text-holder" id="button">
            <div class="body-border load"></div>
            <h2 class="text-holder-click show click-hold-anim" id="click-hold">CLICK AND HOLD</h2>
        </div>
        
        <p>Time Passed While Holding Text:</p>
        <div id="append_here">0</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when that element is held down, the timeout is begun at 2000ms and once it reaches that time, it will change the windows url, as you previously had in a seperate function. If at any moment the mouse goes up on that element with id="click-hold", that timeout will be cleared and nothing should happen.

I've tested this in my own html files and it has worked properly, so please ask further if something isn't working properly

Comment: @Musiix, i should use "let" because inside the function, the timeout_id was being redeclare again? somehow i got stuck, the page seems to be wont get redirected at all. I already tried changing the "#click-hold" to the "id" i'm using for the click and hold, but the page wont change

Comment: @rayn schedio, I've added the html that I use alongside that JS. Maybe that will help! It's working for me on my computer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Musilix, yes it is working, however, what i mean is. When pressing the mousedown it will trigger the count 2000ms, but the page dont change, only after the condition of mousedown > 2000ms passes and mouseup, then the page change. But if the mousedown are below 2000ms, the mouseup event wont trigger the redirecting page.
I'm sorry maybe my explanation wasn't clear since i'm still learning and trying to convert the language to words :)

Comment: @rayn schedio, sorry so much for the confusion. It was a bit unclear, but I believe I have gotten it now. I've changed the code snippet, let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Musilix! it works like a charm! Best Regards :)

Comment: Nice! Make sure to accept my answer for other users' future use, if you're good with it.

Comment: Off course!! I hope you will help me more in the future regarding things i have difficulty on. Thank you!